# sort list by double variable and view the 5 first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a variable "score" in a class team. Now I need a list of teams ordered by score and a viewbag of the first 5 teams.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: `list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Score).Take(5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a collection of teams:

```
ViewBag.TopFive = teams.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a learning assignment, so I will not write any code.

Since you are looking for the first five items, sorting the list may prove too expensive, especially when the list is very long. Instead, you can walk the list, and pick the top five elements.

Seed your five-element "top list" with the initial five elements of the original list, then sort the top list. Since its size is fixed, sorting its five elements is `O(1)`. Now walk the remaining `N-5` elements of the original list, comparing each item to the smallest element of the sorted "top list". If you see a value that's bigger than the smallest item of the top five list, replace one of the top items with the current item, and let the smallest item "fall off" the end of the list. This whole process is `O(N)`, which may be a significant improvement over a sorting solution, which is `O(N*logN)`.

Comment: Neat answer. Question though: Don't you have to continually resort the five-element list such that you are always kicking off the lowest element?

Comment: @LeviBotelho You can search the list (up to four additional comparisons if you just walk the list; three comparisons if you get creative, and use "binary search", but in case of only five elements it's hardly worth the effort) and insert at the correct position. The move takes zero through four reassignments.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Everytime I see an answer from you I stop and read, your answers always contain good information and are very well explained. You should write a book.